# Listen to all child component emitted events in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a child component that wraps a 3rd party video component. How do I listen to all events emitted from this child component?

```
<event-emitter
    v-on:play="handleEvent"
    v-on:stop="handleEvent"
    v-on:ad-pause="handleEvent"
    v-on:ad-play="handleEvent"
    v-on:video-quartile-25="handleEvent"
    v-on:video-quartile-50="handleEvent"
    ... this could many more lines ...
 ></event-emitter>
```

an event could look like this `{ type: "play", time: 28, ... }`

Currently I have this

```
 <event-emitter v-on:emitter-events="handleEvent"></event-emitter>
```

Inside the `<event-emitter>` I consolidate all the emitted events as single event, with a type property. There's a draw back now because the handleEvent function is likely to become long switch statement. Is there a means to be more declarative?

E.g

```
 <event-emitter 
   v-on:listen-to-all-events="normalHander"
   v-on:something-unusal-has-happend="aHandlerForThisVariationOfEvent"
 ></event-emitter>
```

Comment: I think it is a better choice to receive different types of obejct through an event function

Comment: Maybe use event type in function name? Like this["handler"+[event.type]]() though I'm not sure would minimizer do away with function names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just wrote it all inside the parent component, where the `<parent>` acted as a controller to the rest app. Not declarative as I would hoped — and definitely doesn't answer the question though. I don't think it's possible as described.

That event bus link that @Gander provided, is still useful though.

```
<parent> <-- I handle the EmitterEvents
  <somthing-else />
  <event-emitter v-bind:emitter-events="handleEmitterEvents" />
  <another-component />
</parent>
```